# mxGraph and ckEditor on touch devices

Tags: javascript, html, touch, ckeditor, mxgraph

I am trying to develop a web application which uses both mxGraph and CKeditor. This application is intended to be used on both desktop and touch devices.

My issue arises when one uses the application on touch devices. CKeditor has a ‘combo box’ option which allows users to change the font, size etcetera of their content. On a touch device, this works correctly however as soon as an instance of mxGraph is on the page, it is impossible to select one of the options in the combo box (at least on iOS). It behaves correctly in a desktop environment.

I have created a sample code which you can use to reproduce the issue. Just run it on a touch device and try to use the combo box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.2.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
                function main(){
                    var container = document.createElement('div');
                    document.body.appendChild(container);
                    var root = new mxCell();
                    var model = new mxGraphModel(root);
                    // Create an mxGraph on the page.
                    var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);
                    // Create a CKeditor on the page.
                    createEditor();
                }
        function createEditor() {
            // Create an empty editor inside the <div id="editor">.
            var config = {};
            CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor', config, '' );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='main()'>
    <!-- This div will hold the editor. -->
    <div id="editor">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me figure out what is causing this and possibly how to correct it? I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Thank you in advance!